# Retrieving data from local database and store it in a list of object

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using [sqflit](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) to store some data .. The data am storing are questions and answers in two different tables .. am trying to retrieve data from the two tables and store them in a list of type question .. like this:

```
Future<bool> getAllQuestions(String poll_id) async {
print("Poll id is: " + poll_id);
var dbClient = await db;
var questions = await dbClient.rawQuery(
    'SELECT * FROM $tableQuestions WHERE $columnQuestionPollId = "$poll_id"');
print(questions);
for (var q in questions) {
  print(resultsOptionsList);
  print('here here!');
  print(q['question_id']);
  var answers = await dbClient.rawQuery(
      'SELECT * FROM $tableOptions WHERE $columnOptionPollId = "$poll_id" AND $columnOptionQuestionId = "${q['question_id']}"');
  print(answers);
  resultsOptionsList.clear();
  for (var o in answers) {
    print(resultsOptionsList);
    resultsOptionsList.add(ResultsOption.fromJson(o));
  }
  print(resultsOptionsList);
  ResultsQuestion ques = new ResultsQuestion(
      required: /*(q['required']).toLowerCase() == 'true'*/ true,
      icon: 'icon',
      title: q[columnQTitle],
      description: q[columnQDescription],
      link: q[columnLink],
      type: q[columnType],
      maxChoice: q[columnMaxChoice],
      options: resultsOptionsList,
      id: q[columnQId]);
  /*ResultsQuestion ques = ResultsQuestion.fromJson(q);
  ques.options = resultsOptionsList;
  ques.required = true;*/

  resultsList.add(ques);
  print(resultsList[0].options.length);
}
return true;
```

}

Everything is working fine. But the problem is that, now for example I have two questions .. question 1 options are:

> flutter: [{option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149485, text: نعم, answerCount: 5, poll_option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d045314948a, option_question_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149483}, {option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149484, text: لا, answerCount: 10, poll_option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d045314948a, option_question_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149483}]

and question 2 options are:

> flutter: [{option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149489, text: نعم, answerCount: 5, poll_option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d045314948a, option_question_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149486}, {option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149488, text: لا, answerCount: 3, poll_option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d045314948a, option_question_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149486}, {option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149487, text: ربما, answerCount: 7, poll_option_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d045314948a, option_question_id: 5c2c9a8d108d3d0453149486}]

The problem is that it always save the last options list in all question!

for example when I try to print:

```
  print(resultsList[0].options.length);
```

I should get 2 .. but am getting 3 which is the case in

```
  print(resultsList[1].options.length);
```

How to solve this? and what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem myself .. i just moved the declaration of resultsOptionsList right before the for loop .. like this:

```
List<ResultsOption> resultsOptionsList = <ResultsOption>[];
  for (var o in answers) {
    //print(resultsOptionsList);
    resultsOptionsList.add(ResultsOption.fromJson(o));
  }
```

and it was solved :)!

Hopefully will help someone in the future.